# Программа сканирования на предмет наличия файлов ворд

Tags: excel, vba

Какой код должен быть написан в VBAProject документе (Excel)?

Программа позволяющая сканировать выбранную папку на предмет наличия файлов word (анкет соискателей, дизайн которых может быть произвольным) содержащих поля, соответствующие полям таблицы в файле после обнаружения файлов данные из них должны копироваться в таблицу(включая фото).

Comment: Уточните что вы уже сделали, какие видите проблемы. Просто так за вас программу писать никто тут не будет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если вас интересует общий алгоритм:

1. Найти файлы *.doc (Функция `Dir`, например)
2. Каждый файл:

   1. Открыть
   2. Для каждого интересующего параметра (возраст, фио, фото):

      1. Найти по соседним ключевым словам (или первое изображение в документе)
      2. Скопировать
      3. Вставить в нужную ячейку открытого Excel-документа
   3. Закрыть файл и перейти к следующему

Если вас интересует готовая программа - формируйте техническое задание, обращайтесь к фрилансерам.